# file chooser for Nougat or higher

Tags: android, filechooser

I am implementing a file chooser in my android app, I am having 3 different file chooser each for AUDIO, VIDEO, IMAGE.

Its working good below android 7.0, when clicked, its going to gallery for choosing that type of file.

But in Android 7.0, when i am clicking to choose the file picker, its going to RECENT and from there manually i need to go to audio or image gallery, how can i directly go to audio gallery on clicking file chooser as its working in kitkat.

Below  is my code to call the file chooser --

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    //sets the select file to all types of files
    intent.setType("audio/*");
    //allows to select data and return it
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    //starts new activity to select file and return data
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose File to Upload.."),PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: after 7.0 and above you need to use `file provider`  because `'Uri` returns null in &.0 and above